# QGIS: loaded .shp file not displayed

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, display, loading

I am using QGIS 3.10.2-A Coruña and PyQGIS via the internal Python Console (Plugins -> Python Console). Currently I am trying to import a shape file using the following command:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("path/file.shp", "layer_name", "ogr")
```

It seems to be loaded in the sense that I don't get any error message, I can return the column names (fields) and I can also see the attribute table via:

```
iface.showAttributeTable(vlayer)
```

However, the loaded .shp file is neither displayed in the list of layers nor is the corresponding map shown in the main window. I don't have that issue when loading files from a geoPackage or with point vector layers.

What do I have to do differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it works by replacing a shapefile with a geopackage?

What you are doing doesn't ask QGIS to add it to the map canvas. You are only creating the python variable `vlayer` in the memory, representing a vector layer.

After the [layer creation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers), you must [add it to the project](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#qgsproject-instance) :

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works! I thought it did with geopackage, but that's just from my notes from a tutorial I did some time ago, so you're probably right and it doesn't without the additional .instance() command.